# Are there any vegetarian or vegan Masters apart from Anand?

Tags: famous-players

Are there any other vegetarian or vegan chess GM players, apart from Vishy Anand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search turns up the following two:

[Jonathan Speelman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Speelman). Three time British champion and at one point #4 on ELO rating list.

[Peter Leko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Leko). *Almost* World Champion at one point.

**Sources:**

http://www.unleashed.org.au/who_cares/vegetarian_athletes.php?athlete=jonathan-speelman

http://www.veganwolf.com/famous_vegetarians.htm

http://www.veggieboards.com/forum/11-vegetarian-support-forum/72707-chess-world-champion-vegetarian.html

http://chess.jliptrap.us/grandmasterdiet.htm